# overloading primitive variables

Tags: java

code is

```
public class TestOverload {

    public static void print(Float f, double d) {
        System.out.println("Float,double");
    }

    public static void print(float f, double d) {
        System.out.println("float,double");
    }

    public static void print(int f, double d) {
        System.out.println("int,double");
    }
//  public static void print(int f, float d) {
//      System.out.println("int,float");
//  }

    public static void print(double d1, double d) {
        System.out.println("double,double");
    }

    public static void print(float d1, float d) {
        System.out.println("float,float");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestOverload.print(2, 3.0);

        TestOverload.print(2, 3.0f);//Compiler error:The method print(float, double) is ambiguous for the type TestOverload
    }
}
```

why it is giving error , instead it should pick print(float d1, float d)

PS:
in the above code,if i comment :

```
//  public static void print(int f, double d) {
//      System.out.println("int,double");
//  }
```

then print(float d1, float d) is called...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
print(2, 3.0f);
```

Could be both `print(int, float)` and `print(float, double)` since implicit type conversions are done in the backgound. An `int` can be converted to a `float`. Javac (or the compiler) cannot know for sure which one you meant.

If you want to choose for your self you can add casts:

```
print((float) 2, (float) 3.0f);
```

*(Note that the second cast (float => float) isn't necessary.)*

Comment: I think "(float) 3.0f" is redundant, 3.0f is a float without any ambiguities

Comment: I tried @jain007 code, and I can't get his error. I'm getting `int,float` printed, so you must be right. But why? Does it depend on the JAVA version?

Comment: @sp00m the thing is i have commented out the code //  public static void print(int f, float d) {
//      System.out.println("int,float");
//  }

Comment: @jain007 Oh yeah, sorry, I understood that is was when commented that the error appeared. Alright :)

Comment: @sp00m: No it doesn't have anything with the java version. It's how the compiler automatically converts primitives. An `int` can be a `long` aswell as an `float` and `double`. The conversion is done when compiling and in this case two methods can be choosen so you will need to cast the arguments so that the compiler cannot choose for itself!